# Octave 4.2.1 octave-gui : cannot find libgfortran.so.3

Tags: octave, gfortran, archlinux

I am currently having an issue with `Octave` install in `Archlinux.` I am not able to load the current version of `Octave 4.2.1` in `Arch`. It shows the following message -

```
/usr/lib/octave/4.2.1/exec/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/octave-gui: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This problem with `libgfortran.so.3` is not rare. Here are two similar problems happening in `R` [1](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=226849) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch). If somebody using `Octave` on `Archlinux` came across this issue, can you share how to resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: The accepted answer of the stackoverflow question that you linked to says, "If you install an older version of `gfortran` you will get `libgfortran.so.3`. It is completely fine to have multiple versions in your system." Did you try that? What worked and what didn't?

Comment: Have you installed GNU Octave from source or via package manager (pacman)?

Comment: I have installed it via pacman.

Comment: So when you saw whis https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch why didn't it help you? Why should I not close this question as a duplicate of question 2? Please explain.

Comment: From question 1 *"So ... rebuild your locally installed quantreg R package, or install gcc5 and mark the thread as solved.  The former is probably a much better approach."* So did you try rebuilding Octave or installing gcc 5? If not, why not?

Comment: Just give a second - I am giving you an answer.

Comment: I am installing gcc4.9 - my system at the moment contains gcc5. Also I have a feeling that my problem is coming from "octave-gui" package  - so it is little different.

Comment: @VladimirF - the problem is yet to be solved . I installed gcc49.

Comment: And what happened? If your system contains gcc5, it should contain libgfortran.so.3 Which versions of libgfortran can you find in your /usr/lib64 /usr/local/lib64 /usr/lib /usr/local/lib and similar directories? Try to execute `locate libgfortran`. What is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151840/discussion-between-motiur-and-vladimir-f).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it became apparent that the solution from the referenced question [R v3.4.0-2 unable to find libgfortran.so.3 on Arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch) needs to be appended, because the way the older GCC versions will be typically installed in Arch Linux is in a different path.

So, one must find, where the older version is installed, like

```
   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/5.4.0/libgfortran.so.3
```

(depending on the exact GCC version)

and then add the version to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or make a symlik of the library from the above path to `/usr/lib64/`.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because I installed earlier additionally *openblas-lapack* from AUR for better octave matrix multiplication performance. Updating *openblas-lapack* to newest version in AUR did the trick for me.