# How to install libgfortran.so.4 on ubuntu 16.06

Tags: ubuntu, fortran, ubuntu-16.04, gfortran

An app I use just updated and it no longer runs on my system. When I try to run the application I get the error: `error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I looked on my system and only libgfortran.so.3 is available. Do you know what should I do to have the next version also? Which package should I install? (my system is ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: Same issue aft Ubuntu upgraded to 20.04. So annoying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an inverse problem to [R v3.4.0-2 unable to find libgfortran.so.3 on Arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch)

So you must install GCC 7 including the Fortran part, that includes libgfortran 4.

There are answers describing how to do that at other StackExchange sites:

- [Answer 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/859256/how-to-install-gcc-7-or-clang-4-0)
- [Answer 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/914885/installing-gcc-7-and-newer-packages-in-ubuntu-16-04)
- [Answer 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371737/install-gcc-7-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I installed gcc-7 and gfortran-7 and the error is gone now.

Answer (score 10):

You should do the following for solving the problem

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1
```

`sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-7 g++-7
sudo apt-get install gfortran-7
```

Comment: The repository is probably no longer available, based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388960/how-to-resolve-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libgfortran-so-4