# Can't get R to recognize installed libgfortran when installing packages

Tags: r, homebrew, gfortran

I'm trying to install packages in R that depend on libgfortran, but I keep getting this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/7/libgfortran.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/r/3.4.3_1/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I have gfortran installed through homebrew gcc:

```
 ❯❯ readlink `which gfortran`
../Cellar/gcc/8.2.0/bin/gfortran
```

There's a libgfortran available at `/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/8/libgfortran.5.dylib`, but this is not the one R is looking for. How do I convince R to look for gcc 8 instead of gcc 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How do I convince R to look for gcc 8 instead of gcc 7?"

You should not do that! Those libraries are NOT compatible, that's why soname is changed. The ABI is different. You need the correct version of GCC which was used to compile your R package. See very similar (but Linux) questions and answers like [R v3.4.0-2 unable to find libgfortran.so.3 on Arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch) [How to install libgfortran.so.4 on ubuntu 16.06](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516394/how-to-install-libgfortran-so-4-on-ubuntu-16-06)

You really need the compatible library or update your R to a version that uses GCC 8.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.