# Lavaan don't work with libgfortran.so.4, should I file a bugreport?

Tags: r, gcc, gfortran, r-lavaan, solus

Working on Solus Linux I get following error:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/aaron/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.4/quadprog/libs/quadprog.so':
  libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I try to install lavaan. Stated here: [R v3.4.0-2 unable to find libgfortran.so.3 on Arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch) this is due to the most recent version of gcc which upgrades gfortran which updates libgfortran.so.3 to libgfortran.so.4.

Now I could install a old version of gcc (but I have no idea to do that under Solus) or I could ask the Developer (Yves Rosseel) of lavaan to add suppourt to the newest gfortran version and file a bu report?

What would you do?

Comment: File a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

After I filed a bug report, it turns out that Yves Rossell has the most recent version of libgfortran.so.4 (and only this version). So it's clearly not that lavaan is not up to date. Actually I wasn't. I just had to reinstall some dependencies of lavaan:

```
install.packages("pbivnorm")
install.packages("mnormt")
install.packages("numDeriv")
install.packages("quadprog")
```

Thanks Yves.

Answer (score 0):

in the meanwhile you can link the libraries and create libgfortran.so.3 as an alias of libgfortran.so.4

here's how to do it: https://www.bibliotechzw.com/blog/solved-how-to-create-aliases-in-ubuntu-16-via-the-commandline/

Comment: This is not a good idea. There is  good reason why the version vwas increased. The versions are NOT compatible. The version number was increased to avoid linking a wrong incompatible inadvertently.