# conda gfortran on osx failed link issue

Tags: python, macos, fortran, anaconda, gfortran

This issue is apparently well known and widely referenced. I'm running a python 
code using a `conda` installed environment on OSX. I'm getting

> ImportError: dlopen(/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libgfortran.3.dylib

This happens regardless of whether I install `gcc` in the environment. All the suggested work arounds I found aren't applicable to my case. It's been hours of googling.

Can someone please provide relevant suggestion to get over this hump?

Comment: Please tell us *how* and *where* did you install GCC, whether it was a full build of gcc including Fortran and also which workarounds did you try? What kind of code is causing the error?

Comment: I installed gcc on the mac before. don't remember how (can I find out with some command?). Just now I tried using conda install -c anaconda gcc. I am running sample jupyter notebook code https://github.com/fastai/courses/blob/master/deeplearning2/neural-style.ipynb and the error is as shown in my first post.

Comment: But  does your GCC include Fortran? Which version of gfortran it it?

Comment: when I do a locate fortran, I see instances of it all over the place. in /Applications/Octave.app, /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework, all of my conda envs,  ~/macports, /user/local/Cellar/gcc, /userlocal/bin. /usr/local/lib/pythonxx/site-packages. gcc itself is from /usr/bin. Does this point out where I am at?

Comment: Do you have `libgfortran.3.dylib`? Can you execute `gfortran -v`? What does it return when you execute it?

Comment: yes it returns gcc version 7.3.0 (Homebrew GCC 7.3.0). The executable is at /usr/local/bin/gfortran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gfortran is too new for your version of Python. Your Python requires libgfortran version 3, but GCC 7 has libgfortran version 4. You will have to install GCC version 6 or older.

See a similar issue on Linux [R v3.4.0-2 unable to find libgfortran.so.3 on Arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch)

Comment: you are prob right. I already upgrade to python 3 and this problem went away.

Comment: could you help out again. I have to run both python 2 and 3 on my mac. How do I get python2 to find the older version of gfortran (4.9) when the default path points to version 7?

Comment: Hard to say without your configuration. You could ask a new question. Does OSX use LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD or similar? Where are the GCC versions installed? Which exact errors you got now? We can't solve that here.