# How to install libgfortran.so.3 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gfortran, ubuntu-20.04

When I try to install `libgfortran.so.3` on Ubuntu 20.04 using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran3
```

it shows:

```
E: Unable to locate package libgfortran3
```

How can I install Fortran on 20.04?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox  It does not really make sense to mark every other word as code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298364/is-my-assessment-of-this-edit-suggestion-fair

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that 20.04 doesn't support g++-6. To get around this you need a multi-step process:

1. Put a temporary repository into /etc/apt/sources.list. For me that was `deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main universe`
2. Now you can install gcc version 6 `sudo apt-get install g++-6`
3. Make that the default version `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-6 6`
4. Now install gfortran `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3`
5. Make sure it works `strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0 | grep GFORTRAN*`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Nevertheless I have the impression you could add also `apt-get update` somewhere between step 1 and 2. This will help a lot of new comers :-)

Comment: Thanks Edmund, it helped me a lot, and I just find step 3 is not necessary. :)

Comment: Getting error  at step 2: `sudo apt-get install g++-6`  
Package g++-6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'g++-6' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

To install libgfortran libraries in Ubuntu 20.04:

1. First install gcc version 6
2. Then install libgfrotran3

Use this link to download the files.
[Click here](https://gist.github.com/sakethramanujam/faf5b677b6505437dbdd82170ac55322)

Answer (score 0):

libgfortran3 is not supported any more in Ubuntu 20.04 as it depends on an older version of gcc, which is no longer maintained in this version of the distribution.
You can install a later version of libgfortran using:

```
sudo apt-get install libgfortran5
```

Comment: I fear it may not satisfy the dependencies of the OP's software. Major versions of libgfortran are not backwards compatible. We had several similar questions before, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658867/r-v3-4-0-2-unable-to-find-libgfortran-so-3-on-arch?noredirect=1&lq=1 In general, it is possible to have severalversions of GCC in one computer and it is possible to install an old GCC by compiling from source or by getting a binary somewhere.

Comment: @VladimirF I am having a similar problem. My program needs libgfortran3 but after trying everything I can not find a way to install it. Can you tell me how to install gcc6 in ubuntu 20.04? Many thanks!

Comment: @JoanaCarvalho Just download the source code and compile it. Follow the documentation https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC and https://gcc.gnu.org/install/index.html If you have any specific problems, open a question on this site.